# Преобразовать Map в Map через stream api

Tags: java, map, java-stream

Есть объект, и есть view для этого объекта.
Есть `Map<String, List<MyObject>>`. Необходимо получить `Map<String, List<MyObjectView>>`.
Сейчас я это делаю так:

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> map;
Map<String, List<MyObjectView>> response = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<MyObject>> m : map.entrySet()) {
    List<MyObjectView> dtos = m.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(Function<>)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    response.put(m.getKey(), dtos);
}
```

В .map с помощью Function происходит преобразование MyObject в MyObjectView.
Можно ли то же самое сделать без создания дополнительной Map-ы(response)?

Comment: Как Object преобразовывается во View? Что за конструкция `.map(Function<>)`?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно было бы, если бы у `MyObject` и `MyObjectView` был общий супертип

```
Map<String, List<? extends MyType>> map = ...;

map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.stream()
                          .map(function)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Но так как типы разные, придётся сгенерировать новое отображение

```
Map<String, List<MyObjectView>> response = map.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            e - > e.getValue()
                                   .stream()
                                   .map(function)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так намного красивее.